# while installing java on my Ubuntu server using Cloudera manager i am getting below error

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

While installing java on my Ubuntu server using Cloudera manager I am getting below error:
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ21J.png)

I need help creating a single node cluster. I am new to this technology

Comment: Show your error message as text. Other wise we can't help you

Comment: Installation failed. Failed to receive heartbeat from agent.

Comment: Ensure that the host's hostname is configured properly.
Ensure that port 7182 is accessible on the Cloudera Manager Server (check firewall rules).
Ensure that ports 9000 and 9001 are not in use on the host being added.
Check agent logs in /var/log/cloudera-scm-agent/ on the host being added. (Some of the logs can be found in the installation details).

Comment: check this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213364/telnet-connection-closed-by-foreign-host